Overstay ban appeal
I'm a Namibian citizen. I overstayed 7 days in South Africa last year. I was told that my ban is for a year. I appealed but since last year I haven't received any confirmation or waiver to present at the border.
Can I travel to South Africa after my ban is done with proof of emails sent as well as all requested documents? Will they allow me to enter or what can I do next?
